# How Can i Search on Elasticsearch 5x

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-net

I created an object and i want to search this object as an fields value. There is no problem Elasticsearch connection. also i can get all data when i use AllIndices. but i cannot get a value when search as a field. What is the problem? i follow the own Elasticsearch document.

This is My Code

```
        var person = new Person
        {
            Id = 3,
            Firstname = "TOM",
            Lastname = "Brandly"
        };
        if (!client.IndexExists("person").Exists)
        {
            client.CreateIndex("person");
        }

        var indexResponse = client.Index(person);

                     var searchResult = client.Search<Person>(s => s
                           .From(0)
                           .Size(10)
                           .Query(q => q
                           .Term(p => p.Firstname, "TOM")));
```

Comment: From your code snippet I can see that you index person with firstname "TOM" and then are trying to find person with firstname "Serkan".

Comment: Try searching for lowercase text, like `tom` or `serkan`.